# How format a one line npm script in multiple lines in package.json?

Tags: angular, npm-scripts

I have the following npm scipt:

```
ng build core --configuration production && ng build module-one --configuration production && ng build module-two --configuration production && ng build module-three --configuration production && ng build module-four --configuration production && ng build automate --configuration production && ng build store --configuration production",
```

I tried to add the skipping char `\` before a line break but it breaks the code:

```
ng build core --configuration production && ng build module-one --configuration production && \
ng build module-two --configuration production && ng build module-three --configuration production && \
ng build module-four --configuration production && ng build automate --configuration production && \
ng build store --configuration production"
```

This is a styling choice to improve code readability, without functional difference.

Comment: In `package.json`? You can't, JSON doesn't support that.

Comment: To improve readability, you can create additional scripts and run them: script1 && script2...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36258456/how-can-i-write-multiline-scripts-in-npm-scripts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is: not possible, because `.json` doesn't support skiping of line breaks. However, there are some ways of improving readability.
One of them is to break the script into smaller scripts and chain them in another script:

```
"scripts": {
  "bCore": "ng build core --configuration production",
  "bOne": "ng build module-one --configuration production",
  "bTwo": "ng build module-two --configuration production",
  "bThree: "ng build module-three --configuration production",
  "bFour": "ng build module-four --configuration production",
  "bAutomate": "ng build automate --configuration production",
  "bStore": "ng build store --configuration production",
  "build" : "npm run bCore && npm run bOne && npm run bTwo && npm run bThree && npm run bFour && npm run bAutomate && npm run bStore"
}
```