# Script not executable in mac

Tags: python, permissions

I have a python script (scriptname.sh) that gets created with permissions such that it isn't executalbe (Permission denied when try to execute it).

at the command line for mac, I can do the following at the mac command line

```
chmod 775 scriptname.sh
```

and it will execute. This gives -rwxrwx-x permissions.

I tried doing that programmatically in a python script that creates it with

```
os.chmod(filenamePath, 755)
```

but it gives --wxrw--wx and won't execute.

What should I put in the python script so that the permissions will be correct to execute the script at the command line?

(Updated) I also tried running the script at the bash prompt (with permissions given with os.chmod above) and scriptname.sh isn't executable at the command line with

```
./scriptname.sh
```

I looked at [chmod](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16249440/changing-file-permission-in-python), and I'm setting permissions in python a way that is mentioned.  I also looked at [permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12276507/run-script-on-mac-prompt-permission-denied) to see what permissions (755) are needed to be able to execute the script.  I'm not sure why changing it to 755 is behaving different ways at the command line vs programmatically.

Comment: Why are the permissions 775 in the command and 755 in the script?

Comment: Maybe it wants a base 8 number. What happens if you do `os.chmod(filenamePath, int("775", 8))`?

Comment: That worked!!! I didn't need bash either!  Thank you so much!!!  If you post that solution, I'll give you credit for the answer!

Comment: I had to do:  source scriptname.sh on mac also at the command prompt, FYI.

Answer (score 1):

It expects octal, so use

```
os.chmod(yourfile, 0775)
```

On python3

```
os.chmod(yourfile, 0o775)
```

Answer (score -1):

You are making the common mistake of passing a base-10 number to something that wants base-8 flags. The decimal equiv of octal 775 is 509 and for 755, 493